# Group by with maximum date

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want to select data from a table, group by this data with the date value maximum.

In my table i have 4 columns - `id, message_id, client_id and date`. column id is unique and auto incremented, while message_id and client_id have duplicate values. date is almost unique.
I want to `select all records, group by message_id and client_id, that has date maximum`.

my query is -

```
SELECT *,MAX(`date`) AS `maxdate` FROM `table_name` group by `message_id`,`client_id` order by `date` desc
```

but this does not give the date with maximum value.
I am getting the grouped record with first date.

Please help, and tell me the correct query, i am quite new to mysql.

Comment: Your query seems to be correct for what you're asking. Maybe try supplying some example data. You want to retrieve also the id corresponding to the maximum date? If so, you need a self-join as detailed below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query out - this is how I would do it in Oracle:

```
select n1.id, n1.message_id, n1.client_id, n1.date
from shailjas_note n1
where n1.date = (select max(n2.date)
                  from shailjas_note n2
                  where n1.message_id = n2.message_id
                      and n1.client_id = n2.client_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your query.. It did what i wanted.
In my query i just needed to add this - ` order by `maxdate` desc`